# How to horizontally center a Text in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I’m trying to horizontally center a text. Please check the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[_buildTitle()],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildTitle() {
    return 
    Center(child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
      child: Column(
        
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "something.xyz",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25,),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),);
    
  }
}
```

This did not center horizontally, instead gave the following output. The margins etc is fine.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can try the column property `crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.center`

Comment: @Ryosuke: That didn't work

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: LoginPage()));

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[_buildTitle()],
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTitle() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "something.xyz",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
              // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well it is good, but I do not need to horizontal everything. The `title` is the first thing I am adding to the screen, there will be many other elements. When you horizontally align the `row` inside `Scaffold`, everything get horizontally aligned.

Comment: what did you want to achieve? you want the same text on centre or what?

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I made some changes and now it works. I will post my code soon.

Answer (score 29):

You can also solve it with a `Container` and `TextAlign`:

```dart
Container(
   width: double.infinity,
   child: Text(
      'something.xyz',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
   ),
)
```

In this case, the container takes up the entire width with `double.infinity`. The text adapts to the container and can be moved to the middle of the screen with `TextAlign.center`.

Answer (score 14):

more simple way:

```
child: Center(
               child: Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Text('Sunday', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                 ],
               ),
             ), //Center
```

Answer (score 14):

set

```
child: Center(
    child: Text(
      "Hello World",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ),
```

in program

Answer (score 13):

I added my own widget for this use case which is much shorter than the row solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CenterHorizontal extends StatelessWidget {   

    CenterHorizontal(this.child);   
    final Widget child;

    @override   
   Widget build(BuildContext context) => 
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: [child]); 
}
```

the result is this:

```
CenterHorizontal(Text('this is horizontal centered'))
```

Comment: I feel a named argument could improve the usage:   const CenterHorizontal({super.key, required this.child});

Answer (score 5):

```
  Widget textSection = Container(
      child: Text(
      'This can be several lines centered in the child of a container Widget.',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 15.0,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you just want to center horizontally the title, not the other elements that may come after I suppose.

Take a look at the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          title: Text("DEMO"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[_buildTitle()],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // add other elements that you don't to center horizontally
                    Text(
                      "other elements here",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 25,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }

  Widget _buildTitle() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
      child: Text(
        "something.xyz",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 25,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result that gives: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSWLX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: const Text(
    "Hello World!",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Flutter now recommends `SizedBox` for white space

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Text('Hello World',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.White,
      fontSize: 16.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),
```